# Auto-Incremented value not working in PostgreSQL when using EntityFramework Core

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

It seems like the auto-increment function for PostgreSQL doesn't seem to work.

I have the following code:

```
namespace project.Models
{
   public class DatabaseModel
   {
       [Key]
       [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
       [Column(Order=1, TypeName="integer")]
       public int ID { get; set; }
   }
 }
```

When I update the database (after doing a migration) the ID column is the primary key without being a auto-increment.

When I try to add a new object to the database I get the following error:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext[1]
  An exception occurred in the database while saving changes.
  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> Npgsql.PostgresException: 23502: null value in column "ID" violates not-null constraint
```

Can anyone help solve this problem? How can I get the key to be auto-incremented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you created the column with the specific type `integer` you need to specify the type as `serial` for PostgreSQL to generate the id for you.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Comment: This is no longer the case. PostgreSQL for EFCore now natively supports identity columns. https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/modeling/generated-properties.html

Answer (score 9):

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ID { get; set; }
```

To use `identity columns` for all *value-generated* properties on a new model, simply place the following in your `DBContext`'s `OnModelCreating()` event handler:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) 
{
    builder.ForNpgsqlUseIdentityColumns();
}
```

This will assure all keys and other properties which have `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` use `Identity` by default.

You can use `ForNpgsqlUseIdentityAlwaysColumns()` to have `Identity` always, and you can also specify identity on a property-by-property basis with `UseNpgsqlIdentityColumn()` and `UseNpgsqlIdentityAlwaysColumn()`.

[postgres efcore value generation](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/value-generation.html)

Comment: Just a quick note that presently Entity Framework does not require (nor supports) this pattern: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.UseSerialColumns();

    }
```

You should use this in your DbContextClass to create auto incremented value for primary key