# EF Core Migration and PostgreSQL - getting error with auto increment column

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-migrations

I'm getting the below error when adding a migration for postgresql with test data.

The add-migration is working if I specify the Id in the HasData method.

> The seed entity for entity type 'Employee' cannot be added because a
> non-zero value is required for property 'Id'. Consider providing a
> negative value to avoid collisions with non-seed data.

Employee model

```cs
public class Employee
{
      [Key]
      public int Id { get; set; }

      public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In OnModelCreating method

```cs
modelBuilder.HasPostgresExtension("uuid-ossp")
    .UseIdentityColumns();

modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>(e =>
{
    e.Property(p => p.Id).UseIdentityAlwaysColumn();
    e.HasData(
                new Employee { Name = "Name1" },
                new Employee { Name = "Name2" },
                new Employee { Name = "Name3" }
            );
});
```

Comment: Why are you configuring it twice?

Comment: @Aluan Haddad I've read it on one comment that settings the attributes in the model, [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] doesn't work for postgres. So I added identity using fluent api.

Here's the stackoverflow link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40341855/auto-incremented-value-not-working-in-postgresql-when-using-entityframework-core

Comment: But then you would remove the attribute

Comment: It still doesn't work even after removing the attribute. I also have the HasData on the employee to add data. I forgot to add it on my question. Will update it in a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to a friend about this issue and he was able to find out why. Basically, if you use `HasData` to insert data on your table, you must provide the key. It's a requirement.

Here's the explanation from microsoft, [Data Seeding - Limitations of model seed data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#limitations-of-model-seed-data)

So this answered my question. What I need to do now is to add the Id value specifically.