# Repeated key value violates the uniqueness restriction in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I do my course project with EF Core. Often I get this exception:

> PostgresException: 23505: повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности "PK_Logs" DETAIL: Detail redacted as it may contain sensitive data. Specify 'Include Error Detail' in the connection string to include this information.

I have these tables - **Employees**:

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public string Login { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MinLength(2)]
    public string FullName { get; set; } = null!;
    [Required]
    public string Position { get; set; }
    //TODO: сделать ограничения на значения от 0 до 3
    [Required]
    public int RightsLevel { get; set; }
    
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public Employee(string Login, string Password, string FullName, string Position, int RightsLevel, bool IsDeleted=false)
    {
        this.Login = Login;
        this.Password = Password;
        this.FullName = FullName;
        this.Position = Position;
        this.RightsLevel = RightsLevel;
        this.IsDeleted=IsDeleted;
    }

    public virtual List<Log> Logs { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Disbursements_Return>? Disbursements_Returns { get; set;}
    public virtual List<BookRenewal>? Renewals { get; set; }
}
```

**Log**:

```
public class Log
{
    [Key]
    public int LogId { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public Log(string message, DateTime date )
    {
        this.Message = message;
        this.Date = date;
    }
}
```

I also have this `AppDbContext` class:

```
namespace AppDbContextForEasyLib
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        //TODO: Добавить поля IsDeleted и LastChange
        //TODO: Настроить ограничения

        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Reader> Readers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BookEdition> BookEditions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BookCopy> BookCopies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Disbursements_Return> Disbursements { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BookRenewal> BookRenewals { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BookPlace> BookPlaces { get; set; }
        public DbSet<KnowledgesArea> KnowledgesAreas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Log> Logs { get; set; }
        
        public AppDbContext()
        {
           // Database.EnsureDeleted();
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
        {
        }
        
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);
            optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
#if DEBUG
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=EasyLibTestDb;Username=postgres;Password=pechenka001");
#else
             optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=EasyLibDb;Username=postgres;Password=pechenka001");
#endif
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().Property(e => e.IsDeleted).HasDefaultValue(false);
            
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            //TODO: Починить исключение. Выводится типа "столбца rightslevel не существует"
           // modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
           //.ToTable(e => e.HasCheckConstraint("RightsLevel", "RightsLevel >= 0 AND RightsLevel <= 3"));
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add one method, which I work with database. I decided, that if I add all methods, that will be a lot of text.

```
public static void RecoverEmployee(string login, Employee Author)
{
    AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);

    if (!IsExist(login))
        throw new EmployeeException("Такого пользователя не существует!");

    using (var db = new AppDbContext())
    {
        var emp = db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Login == login);
        emp.IsDeleted = false;

        var log = new Log(AddLogMessage(emp.Login), DateTime.Now);
        log.Employee = Author;
        // Author.Logs.Add(log);
        db.Logs.Add(log);

        db.Employees.Attach(Author);

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Work with Log the same everywhere.

Please, help me, I think already spent 2 days. I tried delete and create database, sequence reset and I tried to rewrite a lot of my code.

Comment: I don't see any sequence of serial configuration on `LogId`. Maybe that's the reason why you getting that error.

Comment: Why are you storing passwords as plaintext in a string column?

Comment: `= null!;` <-- There is no reason to do this. Use a self-documenting pragma instead of subverting nullable warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem. I needed to explicitly specify a one-to-many relationship.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee().Property(e=>e.IsDeleted).HasDefaultValue(false);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasMany(e => e.Logs)
                                   .WithOne(e => e.Employee)
                                   .HasForeignKey(e => e.AuthorLogin)
                                   .IsRequired(true);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Log>().HasOne(e => e.Employee)
                              .WithMany(e => e.Logs)
                              .HasForeignKey(e => e.AuthorLogin)
                              .IsRequired();
           
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you create a **new Log(...)** which is the "child" entity, and you assign its **Employee** property (generating a foreign key referring to the "parent" property) to "Author" object.

To save child and parent together, it's enough to **Add** the new log to the Context and call SaveChanges().

Not use Attach, because doing so, you will make the state of Author to **Unchanged** and it cannot be saved correctly.

Modify your code:

```
public static void RecoverEmployee(string login, Employee Author)
{
    AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);

    if (!IsExist(login))
        throw new EmployeeException("Такого пользователя не существует!");

    using (var db = new AppDbContext())
    {
        var emp = db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Login == login);
        emp.IsDeleted = false;

        var log = new Log(AddLogMessage(emp.Login), DateTime.Now);
        log.Employee = Author;
        
        db.Logs.Add(log);   //log and Author will be saved in one time         

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this method, but EF throw new exception

PostgresException: 23505: повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности "PK_Employees".

I rewrited method and all troubles arise on db.Logs.Add(log);

Comment: Reading this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40341855/auto-incremented-value-not-working-in-postgresql-when-using-entityframework-core , I think it's an AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY Postgres problem related. You should modify your OnModelCreating, adding the line: **modelbuilder.ForNpgsqlUseIdentityAlwaysColumns()**